How to install Components (client tools connectivity and Client tools backwards Compatibility) in SQL Server 2022
I'm installing SQL Server 2022 but I could not select components shown below:

Client tools connectivity
Client tools backwards compatibility
Client Tools SDK

I need these components for my application. How to install these components?
They could be installed in SQL Server 2019, but cannot be installed in SQL Server 2022.
Can anybody help me?
This is the SQL Server 2022 version:

And this is SQL Server 2019:


Why do you want them in the first place? You don't need the SQL Server installer to install SQL Server drivers, they're separate downloads

@PanagiotisKanavos In my case, I have a SQL Server 2022 instance running on a Windows Server Core box, which means I have to use SQL Server Configuration Manager remotely from my main desktop - but I don't want to install the full SQL Server just for that one tiiiiiny component...

I think they've just been unbundled from the installer, and you need to have the client tools packages installed separately, or available for the installer to bootstrap.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/oledb/download-oledb-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Thanks for your response. I'll give it a try.

The links you posted are for only the ODBC Driver and OLE-DB Provider, respectively - they don't include the SQL Server Configuration Manager MMC snap-in needed to remotely-configure a SQL Server 2022 instance running on Windows Server Core...

I agree, the links posted are not answering the question, I have the same issue and am searching for the "Client Tools Connectivity" and "Client Tools Backwards Compatibility" for SQL Server 2022 version and am unable to find them. Anyone who was able to solve this?

Why do you need them?
